# How to precompile regular expressions?

Tags: regex, postgresql

The PostgreSQL's regular expressions are expressed as strings (`text` datatype),

```
SELECT regexp_matches('foobarbequebaz', '(bar)(beque)'::text);
```

so is natural to imagine it as a dynamic parameter... But no, is not possible to be dynamic... This query *"failed to find conversion function from unknown to text"*,

```
SELECT regexp_matches('foobarbequebaz', (SELECT '(bar)(beque)') );
```

... So, we can imagine something intermediary to **reuse regular expressions**, as [pre-compile it](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/13643.1154379364%40sss.pgh.pa.us). It is possible with PostgreSQL  v10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message has nothing to do with "dynamic" values or "precompiled" values. It simply tells you that the result of `(SELECT '(bar)(beque)')` has an unknown data type, but `regexp_matches()` expects `text`

So you need to cast that result to text:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('foobarbequebaz', (SELECT '(bar)(beque)')::text );
```

If you want to pass the expressions from somewhere else, you can do it like this:

```
with list_of_expressions (expression) as (
  values 
   ('(bar)(beque)'),
   ('(foo)')
)
SELECT regexp_matches('foobarbequebaz',  expression)
from list_of_expressions;
```

Of course `list_of_expressions` could also be a table in your database.

Comment: Oops, sorry Stackoverflow, I showed how-to and not used the correct syntax by myself  ;-)